# delphi 6 and ADO ms access db

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access

I searched many forums and google on this, but I am still not sure how to find the answer.

I have **Delphi 6 standard (personal edition)**, However, now I am getting into the database scene and I would like to incorporate some of my projects to work with a MS Access database.

Since i have both Office 2000 (home pc) and Office 2003 (work pc) I thought I could import through activex, but the ADO does not show up when I try. But that failed

So how do I go about getting Delphi 6 to be database friendly, with controls, component installation, etc?

What i want to do is create an MS Access database (`.mdb`), and open it through my form controls using a Delphi 6 application.

Comment: It's trivial to migrate any D6 app to D7 or D2007. Why are you stuck on D6?

Comment: Does the personal edition allow db access? Why do you want to use access? Wouldn't a real database be better?

Comment: sorry for not responding properly, there is no [respond back] button.

Comment: to Warren P -- no, the d6 has not db controls.

Comment: to David Heffernan -- i use access because that is my primary tool at work, we use office 2003 professional.  at home i use office 2000 prof.

Comment: to all -- i am not familiar with a "real database".  i only know access, and i write tons of queries for it.  i have started using a grid control (bergs) and am getting comfortable with it, except it does not include filtering or query etc.  so, want to create the .mdb source myself.  then, in my delphi 6 app, connect to it.  then, i will just add to the table (the data) from the app via the grid control.

Comment: to Warren P -- i purchased D6 when it first came out.  at the time, it was $69 at compusa.  i started with turbo pascal 3.0 and purchased all the releases, but stopped when the windows 1 and 2 came out, but i finally purchased 3.0 but stopped again, and then purchased the D6 standard.  the other versions were not available at compusa.  and in later years, they got soo expansive, i just stayed with D6.  i don't know any other version(s) that includes DB features other that i know that they are very expansive if i want the DB features.  i can't affort $500 or $1000 or more for those versions.

Comment: No, you can't get ADO with Delphi standard, personal edition. Other than ADO, you can use BDE with ODBC to access MS Access database. But I don't know if BDE is included in personal ed. Or you can use free MySQL, Postgres, firebird, MS SQL database with free Zeos components.

Comment: Other option is to use FreeDAC to work with MSAccess, which is free.

Comment: i think my other problem could be that i don't have db-aware controls with the d6 standard version.  so, i am still searching around for 3rd party components/controls that are db-aware so that i can work with ado / odbc more effeciently through them.

Comment: i though it wouldn't hurt to ask.. does anyone know if the d6 or d7 enterprise (w/ db-aware etc) still available for purphase ? i took a look around and so far only the latest (XE2) are being sold and they are several $K in price, even the standard (which doesn't come w/ db-aware) is $1k. maybe the 6/7 enterprise is a few hundred.

Comment: No, you can't buy licences for the old products. Real databases are client/server tools. Avoid Access and FileMaker.

Comment: If you are on a budget then strongly consisder C# express